# Start Java Program by Script in Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, shell

I want to start my java program by script. I also want to include .jar files by executing the script.
My script looks like this:

```
if [ -d ./bin ]; then
    rm -fr ./bin
fi 
mkdir ./bin

javac -sourcepath ./src -d ./bin -cp ./../Jars/CFMgr.jar ./src/gui/App.java
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo "compile errors..."
    exit -1
fi
java -classpath ./bin:./../Jars/CFMgr.jar:./../Jars/ojdbc14.jar gui.App
```

Every time I execute it with this command `./script.sh` in the linux terminal, I get the following error:

https://s4.postimg.org/kevatu0nx/Unbenannt.png

Answer (score 0):

test:

```
java -cp "./bin/*:./lib/*" com.YourClass
```

Comment: Hi Youe; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling only `App.java` , which need Panel.java. so compile all the classes in gui package at the same time.

Comment: But Panel.java is in the jar file so how can I solve that?

Comment: if it is in CFMgr.jar, is path of the jar correct ? is it with package gui.Panel?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to export your java program to an `executable jar` and then:

```
java -jar yourProgram.jar
```